# How method .toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator) knows the size of new Array

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking for the answer for a question: how method .toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator) knows the size of new Array.

Actually I know how to use this method to create new Array that contains all of `stream` elements (e.g. `String[]::new, Size -> new String[Size]`), but in the original java code we can see that the `IntFunction<A[]>` generator applies given function to int argument. And there is my question HOW this function gets the number of elements of the stream.

I've been reading the source code of this classes for 3 hours, but I did not find the answer.

Comment: Where are you looking for the toArray() source code?

Comment: The stream is the one which calls the IntFunction. It passes the length of the array to create to the IntFunction. The stream knows how many elements it needs to store in the array (and if it doesn't, it calls the IntFunction several times and concatenates all the arrays).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the answer to your question is stated in java docs.

> [`toArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-) uses the
>   provided *generator* function to allocate the returned array, as well
>   as any additional arrays that might be required for a partitioned
>   execution or for resizing.
>
> The *generator* function takes an integer, which is the size of the
>   desired array and produces an array of the desired size.